# looking for general advice on the field of computer science

Tags: education

I don't have any knowledge at all in the field, i don't know if i am in the correct community. Is there any book you would suggest for a starter to gain an idea about computer science? I have a good background on mathematics and engineering. I want a book to understand get a general idea about the field in order to be able to decide where i should focus.

Thanks

Comment: You could just learn how to program. This path will eventually lead you to computer science. Install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and go ahead, there is a plentora of tutorials on the internet. It's probably easier than just going straight into computer science itself.

Comment: "a general idea about the field" -- is that a thing? What is "the general idea" of mathematics?

Comment: @Gabriel It's perfectly possible to enter CS from mathematics, without ever writing a single line of code.

Comment: @Raphael I agree. I just gave him an idea of something that may be _easier_.

Comment: we just came up with some ideas for you [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40883748#40883748). if you can get a few more SE pts (ie 20 total at _any_ site!) you can join the chat room for further inquiry :)

Comment: @Raphael how it is possible to enter CS from mathematics without writing a single line of code? How can i do it?

Comment: I don't know. I guess you just start reading about things that interest you, and go from there. Maybe mathematicians working in TCS can tell you more. (Not that I think doing CS without having any concept of the practical side is a good idea. But plenty of people do it.)